# How to aggregate data in one column by values in another column using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL that contains demographic data for each province of my country.

```
Columns are: Province_name, professions, Number_of_people.
```

As you can see, Province_names are repeated for each profession.
How then can I get the province names not repeated and instead get the professions in separate columns?

Comment: provide your sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Sry, we don't see anything. Please add sample data and expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pivot your table (Really: It is better to show data and expected output in your question!)

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c075e60b50e910419f2cba6b3f6c2582)

This is the PostgreSQL way (since 9.4) to do that using the `FILTER` clause

```
SELECT
    province,
    SUM(people) FILTER (WHERE profession = 'teacher') AS teacher,
    SUM(people) FILTER (WHERE profession = 'banker') AS banker,
    SUM(people) FILTER (WHERE profession = 'supervillian') AS supervillian
FROM mytable
GROUP BY province
```

If you want to go a more common way, you can use the `CASE` clause

```
SELECT
    province,
    SUM(CASE WHEN profession = 'teacher' THEN people ELSE 0 END) AS teacher,
    SUM(CASE WHEN profession = 'banker' THEN people ELSE 0 END) AS banker,
    SUM(CASE WHEN profession = 'supervillian' THEN people ELSE 0 END) AS supervillian
FROM mytable
GROUP BY province
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I ended up exporting data as CSV and do pivot tables in Excel. Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a pivot which is a little more complicated in Postgresql then in other rdbms. You can use the crosstab function. Find a introduction here: https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function

for you it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab( 'select Province_name, professions, Number_of_people from table1 order by 1,2') 
     AS final_result(Province_name TEXT, data_scientist NUMERIC,data_engineer NUMERIC,data_architect NUMERIC,student NUMERIC);
```